# Select and copy specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that I want to select some cells based on their values then copy these cells to another sheet using VBA.

I have a chunk of code that go through all the excel sheetd and search for a specific value then return the total of this cells.

- I need to copy right now just the cells in column H that have values "name" & "contact" and copy all these values to the sheet2 in the same workbook.
- Then I to copy the cells that are next to the name and contact.
- The end result is a new table that contain 2 columns name and contact and under each column the values of each name and contact that belong to it

Sample Data

[image: sample picture of how the original sheet look like]

[image: sample picture of how the result sheet should become]

## Scan:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

row_number = 4
count_of_str = 0
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & row_number)
    If InStr(item_in_review, "name") Then
      count_of_str = count_of_str + 1
    End If

Loop Until item_in_review = ""
MsgBox "the str occured: " & count_of_str & " times."
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add some more detail about what cells should be copied (just the cell from Col H?), and where they should be copied to.

Comment: i will edit my POST and add some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilise the `Find` / `FindNext` methods

It's not entirely clear which columns your data is in.  I have assumed the labels `name` and `contact` are in `H`, and the actual data in `I`

Also, I have assumed that every `name` will have a `contact`, and have not included any checks for that.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim row_number As Long, count_of_str As Long
    Dim rToSearch  As Range, rFound As Range, rng As Range
    Dim strSearchTerm As String
    Dim FirstAddr As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rDest As Range

    Dim cl As Range, ar As Range
    strSearchTerm = "name"

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rToSearch = .Range(.Cells(5, 8), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set rng = rToSearch.Find( _
      What:=strSearchTerm, _
      After:=rToSearch.Cells(rToSearch.Cells.Count), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlPart, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False, _
      SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddr = rng.Address
        Do
            count_of_str = count_of_str + 1
            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                Set rFound = rng.Offset(0, 1)
            Else
                Set rFound = Union(rFound, rng.Offset(0, 1))
            End If
            Set rng = rToSearch.FindNext(rng)
        Loop Until rng.Address = FirstAddr
    End If

    MsgBox "the str occured: " & count_of_str & " times."
    ' rFound now refers to all found cells

    ' Copy to somewhere
    Set ws = Worksheets("YourDestinationSheet")     '<~~Update as required
    Set rDest = ws.Range("YourDestinationRange")    '<~~Update as required
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        rFound.Copy rDest                           '<~~ copy names
        rFound.Offset(1, 0).Copy rDest.Offset(0, 1) '<~~ copy contacts
    End If

    ' Process found cells
    ' eg
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        For Each ar In rFound.Areas
        For Each cl In ar.Cells
            Debug.Print cl.Address
        Next cl, ar
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this is the perfect solution for my question but its not completed yet because i also need to copy to the other sheet , cells that contain the other value witch is "contact"  how to ad this option to your code ?

Comment: You should be able to extend this code yourself.  If you need more help, aAdd some sample data showing both source and copied sheets.  (Note edit this into your Q)

Comment: i edit my post and add 2 pictures to clarify what i need   take a look on the edit post

Comment: i have some duplicated name where one of each duplicated name first time it displayed without a contact but the second time it display with a contact ... can i check if their is a name without a contact do not copy it ?

Comment: @devleb sure you can, why don't you give it a go

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim count_of_str As Long
    Dim c as Range, d As Range

    count_of_str = 0

    Set c = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H4")  'cell to check
    Set d = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")  'destination to copy to

    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0

        If InStr(c.Value, "name") > 0 Then
            count_of_str = count_of_str + 1
            c.Copy d
            Set d = d.Offset(1, 0)  'next destination row
        End If

        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'next cell to check

    Loop 

    MsgBox "the str occured: " & count_of_str & " times."

End Sub
```

Comment: your code work awesome  now i want to copy the cells that is beside the value "name" so i need to first search about the value "name" then copy the cells beside it